# having trouble deploying node.js app(express,mongo) to heroku

Tags: express, heroku

I am attempting to deploy my node.js app to heroku, and they files successfully upload.  however, when i go to the site I get an application error telling me to look at my logs.  I have no idea how to read the logs as there are numerous lines.  Also, i have tinkered with the Procfile and package.json.

proc file:

```
web: ./bin/www
```

package.json:

```
{
 "name": "myapp",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
   "start": "node ./bin/www"
 },
"dependencies": {
  "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
  "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
  "debug": "~2.2.0",
  "express": "~4.13.1",
  "jade": "~1.11.0",
  "mongodb": "^2.1.7",
  "mongoose": "^4.4.4",
  "morgan": "~1.6.1",
  "node-restful": "^0.2.5",
  "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "react": "^0.14.7"
}
```

}

This is the last line of code in the log:

2016-02-26T00:40:41.013990+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H99desc="Platform error" method=GET path="/" host=nodeguestbook.herokuapp.com request_id=5d709e85-d4d3-4fbe-99de-d0d01aeff8cd fwd="97.90.145.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

When i run locally, my node js app works.

Comment: How are you specifying the port for the app to run?

Answer (score 0):

H99 Platform error indicates something went wrong on heroku's end, as per the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h99-platform-error) it says

> This indicates an internal error in the Heroku platform. Unlike all of
>   the other errors which will require action from you to correct, this
>   one does not require action from you. Try again in a minute, or [check the status site](https://status.heroku.com).

I believe you should wait for sometime and then communicate with Heroku Support.

I hope it helps! Please let me know if you need anything else! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I messaged heroku hopefully they get back to me soon

Comment: I checked the logs again and it says its an h10 error, and according to the logs it just says the app crashed.  Any ideas what this means ?

Comment: Oh, can you share the log for h10? Usually it contains the route. H10 simply means that there was some unhandled exception and the app crashed. If app crashes in few seconds then it means the bootstrapping code at /Bin/www otherwise you get a route which may narrow down the point search! In any case, Ill need some more info. It seems you are using express generator to scaffold. Right? If that the case, then the apps bootstrapping code must be fine. Please share the log... It might give some more insight. With looking at actually code it all guess work! If you know what I mean ;)

Comment: *without looking at actual code.....  (typo) I'm responding from my handheld hence the typos...

Comment: Hi dave, sorry for the late reply, im relatively new to stack overflow and did not see your response.  Anyways, i looked at the logs again here is the code when i try to start the app:

Comment: 2016-02-29T03:43:45.575960+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nodeguestbook.herokuapp.com request_id=41e11e90-c858-4694-a96d-1d2bb08c8bb2 fwd="97.90.145.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: The whole log is quite long, and I can share it with you if you would like.  It appears that  something is going wrong with mongodb.  do you happen to have any experience with having mongodb on your node.js server? i am almost certain this is the issue because i simply uploaded the entire node server, and i just read that the database should be handled separately(yes I am a super noob).  THanks so much for all your help!

Comment: Yes my friend I do have an app in production. We are using mongo-labs... What Mongo server are you using and how do you set connection string. Can you share code snippets?

Comment: Hi again dave, I just figured out how to fix it.  Like you said , i needed the mongolab addon.  My server is up and running now! Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: Welcome! Be awesome! If it helped don't forget to mark it as answer... Others will find solution easily... :)